# How to design a public API to read configration settings?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

This is a general design question. I have the following format configuration file and I'd like to design an API to read it. We should parse strings loaded from the config file and assign the converted values to the related typed objects (to `int` or `string` in this example). Parsing errors could occur during this process.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="countoffiles" value="7" />
    <add key="logfilelocation" value="abc.txt" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I can think of two methods. What are the problems with these two designs? Any comments are appreciated.

One is template method pattern:

```
class Config
{
public:
    virtual bool ParseValues() = 0;
    virtual void SetDefaultValues() = 0;
    bool TrySetValuesOrDefault()
    {
        if (!ParseValues())
        {
            SetDefaultValues();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

class IntType::Config
{
    string str;
public: 
    int output_int;
    IntType(string str){
         this.str = str;
    }
    bool ParseValue() 
    {
        return someParseFoo(str, output_int);
    }
    void SetDefaultValue() 
    {
        output_int = 3;
    }
}
class StringType::Config
{ // similar with IntType
}
```

Since the configuration file is supposed to be only read once at the beginning of the program, the singleton design pattern is desired too.

```
class Config
{
public:
   int output_int;
   string output_str;

   static Config *getInstantce(){
       static Config *instance;
       return instance;
   }
   bool ParseValues_Int()
   {
        return someParseFoo(str, output_int);
   }
   bool ParseValues_String()
   {
        return someParseFoo(str, output_Str);
   }
   void SetDefaultValues_Int() 
   {
       output_int = 3;
   }
   void SetDefaultValues_String() 
   {
       output_Str = "abcd";
   } 
   int getInt(string name, int default)
   {
       if (!ParseValues_Int())
       {
           SetDefaultValues_Int();
       }
       return output_int;
   }
   string getString(string name, string default)
   {// similar with getInt
   }

private:
   Config(){};
   Config(Config const&);
   void operator=(Config const&);
};
```

Comment: I don't see much advantage from the class-based parser. In order to create the correct class you've already done most of the hard work and the caller may well still screw it up by requesting the wrong datatype. Might as well call the appropriate parsing function right there and get the result. Or just leave the whole thing as a string, convert on demand, and cache.

Answer (score -1):

When designing a configuration provider, you should take into consideration:

**Testability and injection**

Design it so that you can inject custom configurations in tests. A a singleton object that always loads from the same XML file is not good enough for this. For tests, you want to be able to create a custom configuration in test code, and inject it into the class or module being tested. If you like XML, you can use XML for defining your test configurations as well. For tests, only define the particular configuration that should be different from default.

For injecting the configurations into your application code, it is advisable to use some kind of IOC container, which stores the configuration. If you are working with some framework that already takes care of that, great. Otherwise, I am not sure if there are very popular libraries that already do this, but I would start by search for existing code (see http://turncoder.blogspot.ru/2014/02/a-simple-c11-ioc-container-thats-all.html for a discussion on this topic). Such an IOC container will be accessible globally, and will typically expose methods for fetching objects by their types.

**Immutability**

As you already indicated, your configuration is immutable, so it should be passed around as `const` object.

**Multiple config objects to reduce coupling**

Don't create lots of single-field config objects, because then you need to pass them around as function arguments, and you'll get functions with lots of arguments. You need to choose whether you put all configurations in one object, or divide them to smaller, more cohesive objects that share a topic. If you're not sure, start by a single configuration object, and then see whether it makes sense to divide, so that each consumer of configurations will only get the configurations it needs. The good thing about a single object is that it makes it easier to pass the configuration around. The bad thing is that it makes everything depend on this one object.

**Support command-line arguments and environment variables**

It is often very helpful to enable to parse configuration not only from XML but also from the command-line and/or from environment variables. This makes it really easy to start instances of the application with custom configurations, either manually or automatically, for debugging or for testing, without bothering to edit an XML file.

Comment: I don't see what earned a downvote here. This isn't a question that can be answered, so Adi pointed out several things worth the OP's time to investigate.

Comment: Thanks Adi for the comments, it's very helpful. From your point of view, my second method, the singleton one, is not desired. The first one should work, but need to put `IntType` and `StringType` to one class, they will be passed around with one object. is it correct?